# How to dynamically change a button title (When a bool has a certain property)

Tags: c++, cocoa-touch, properties, uibutton, setter

I'm learning objective-C, and have started off by making a simple calculator.  I've hit a couple of walls though.  I have 2 displays, the current number being typed in, and a smaller one that displays everything that has been typed in thus far.  I also have a "clear" button.

I want it so that if a user hits the "clear" button once, it clears the main display, and changes it's title to "AC" (all clear).  If it is then hit *again* I want it to clear the smaller display of everything that has been typed in so far.

That all works fine, but I'm having issues because I want the button to go *back* to being just "clear" when the user starts typing in another number.

I have an @property (nonatomic) BOOL userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber;
and an @synthesize for that property.

How can I make it so that whenever userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber == YES, I can set the clear button (or the @property (nonatomic) BOOL allClear) that I have to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to not `@synthesize` the `userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber` property, and write the code for it yourself.

Add a private `BOOL` variable to your class, and write the `userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber` and `setUserIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber:` methods. The getter should return the "backing" variable; the setter should check the old and the new value to see if the old value is `NO` and the new value is `YES`. When this is the case, the setter should change the title of the button as appropriate.

Comment: ok so I could do something like this (I can just leave the @synthesize there so it deals with the getter right?)? - (void) setUserIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber:(BOOL)userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber {
    if (userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber == YES) {
        _allClear = NO;
    }
}  but is there any way to reference the button itself?  Because now I would need to figure out how to change the button title whenever _allClear==NO

Comment: @Acoustic77 I assumed that the property is in the view controller of the view that holds the button, in which case you get a reference to the button "for free". If this is in fact in a different class, add a method in the view controller to set the `userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber` property, and put the logic there. Your implementation is incomplete - you do not change the value of the backing variable.

Comment: in the CalculatorViewController.h I only have properties for my two displays.  And @property (nonatomic) BOOL userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber; is declared in CalculatorViewController.m, where I have the above mentioned stuff.  I'm sorry for being difficult, but I'm very new with this.  when you say "add a method in the view controller" do you mean move the userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringNumber property to the .h?  and what is the "backing variable"?

Comment: @Acoustic77 Where's the button then? The method needs to have access to the button.

Comment: in my CalculatorViewController.m I have this for the button: - (IBAction)clearPressed:(id)sender{if (self.allClear==NO) {NSUInteger dislength=[self.display.text length];self.inputlog.text=[self.inputlog.text substringToIndex:[self.inputlog.text length]-dislength];self.display.text = @"0";[sender setTitle:@"AC" forState:UIControlStateNormal];self.allClear = YES;} else {[sender setTitle:@"AC" forState:UIControlStateNormal];self.inputlog.text = @"";self.display.text = @"0";self.allClear = YES;}}
The button was physically created in the storyboard and ctrl-dragged into the .m to create that action

Comment: ugh, that's a mess^  but basically I made the button in storyboard and ctrl-dragged it into my CalculatorViewController.m as an action

Comment: @Acoustic77 If a button is in a storyboard, there should be an `IBOutlet` for it somewhere, too.

Comment: Oh, the buttons aren't declared in the .h of my view, because they didn't need to be used by other stuff.  So I guess I can declare this one button in the .h so that other stuff can change it.

Comment: @Acoustic77 It's OK for it to be in the class extension in the .m file, as long as it is connected to the NIB correctly.

Comment: what's an NIB?  I declared @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *clearButton; in my CalculatorViewController.h  and I put [self.clearButton setTitle:@"C" forState:UIControlStateNormal]; in the place where I wanted it, but its not changing the title of the button when the program comes to that line.

Comment: got it! Just needed to drag and connect the button to the @property declaration in my .h

Answer (score 0):

in the method viewdidload add the name of the button title as clear

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
[super viewDidLoad];
[myButton setTitle:@"Clear" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

and in the method which clears everything make the button title to AC

```
- (void)clearAllAndACMethod{
if(userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber==Yes)
{
[myButton setTitle:@"AC" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber=NO;
}
else{
another type code and 
[myButton setTitle:@"Clear" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber=YES;
}
//remaining method with  

}
```

CHange the bool value according to your need because i didnt get you bool value correctly I think. try this it will work fine